G has a element of order 2 not lying in center
Let G be order of 8，if G has a element of order 2 not lying center，how to prove G is isomorphic to $D_8$?
A hint is consider the sylow-2 subgroup of $S_4$, I know it's $D_8$. So I want to construct a group action to let $G$ embed in $S_4$, but I can't find the action.

Let $g\in G$ be the element of order two not lying in the center.   Let $G$ act by conjugation on the set of left cosets  of $G/\langle g\rangle .$
So you get a homomorphism from $G$ into $S_4.$
The kernel is $\bigcap_{h\in G}h\langle g\rangle h^{-1}=\{e\},$ because $g$ isn't in the center (prove!).
Thus $G$ is (isomorphic to) the Sylow-$2$ subgroup of $S_4.$
Btw, this is one of the most indispensable actions to know about.

The part of ker is the key! Thank you for your answer!

The kernel of that action is called the normal core of the subgroup you quotient by.

I think it should action on all conjugate class of G about H but not left closet.

Off-hint. Firstly, of course, such a $G$ is nonabelian as there is a noncentral element. Secondly, the existence of a centerless $G$ of order $8$ is prevented by the class equation and the fact the $7$ can't be summed up with terms which are powers of $2$. Moreover, $|Z(G)|\ne 4$, as there isn't any group with nontrivial cyclic quotient $G/Z(G)$. Therefore, $|Z(G)|=2$, and hence, by assumption, there are at least two elements of order $2$. If you know that the quaternion group has one element of order $2$, only, then you are left with $G$ being $D_8$ ($D_4$ for many).

Fine, but your solution relies on the classification of non-abelian groups of order $8$, which is not assumed …

Agreed, @NickyHekster.
